# Loader.as returning blank bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader

I have an application which pulls in Bitmap resources from a server - currently I use the Loader class to do this, then, once they're loaded, generate a BitmapData based on the loader dimensions and draw the instance of Loader directly to it (the BitmapData is used for Away3D textures as well as Bitmap instances, so I have no need for the Loader once fetched).

This has always worked for me, but recently I started getting 0x0 Loaders, and invalid BitmapData as a result.

I stopped doing this:

```
this.imageBitmap = new BitmapData(this.imageLoader.width, this.imageLoader.height, true, 0);
```

..and started doing this:

```
this.imageBitmap = new BitmapData(event.target.content.width, event.target.content.height, true, 0);
```

Where event is the Event.COMPLETE event fired by the loader. This fixed the dimension problem, but the BitmapData is just a plain white bitmap (and it's set to transparent by default, so this is being drawn into it). Frustratingly, this doesn't happen every time, if I refresh the application it works as it should around 25% of the time, otherwise it plays up like this.

I've got a tight deadline and I'm really screwing about this, if anyone could help or suggest a better way of doing it you'd really be saving my neck!

Comment: Sounds like security related issues to me, are you getting the bitmaps from a cross domain?

Comment: Alas no, I fixed the crossdomain problems some time ago and it's currently sandboxed anyway (getting no errors either, just blank Loaders)

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#contentLoaderInfo

Comment: I would run more reflection related code on `event.target.content`, check what type it is and what is it's `LoaderInfo` instance for example. I've seen Flash not report errors when it does not support a bitmap or "mistakes" the file for a stage-blank SWF.

Comment: I'll check but even if there are errors like this I can't see a way round them, and this method has always worked before. Do you know of any other ways to load bitmaps into Flash?

Comment: @MickMalone1983 when you said "event is the Event.COMPLETE event fired by the loader", did you mean the loader itself or its contentloader? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: Sorry, should have specified - the ContentLoader fires it.

Comment: You're looking for width() -- which could be 0 if the item has not rendered yet -- which would make sense that you're getting it sometimes, and not other times.  I would suggest setting your width to contentLoaderInfo.width/height, as those are the published swf sizes.  Then, once you call your BitmapData.draw, it would force the item to render ......

Comment: Thanks, but since I started using the second method the dimensions retrieved have not been a problem, just blank content. It's strange, as I say I've used this method lots of times before with no problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, stupid oversight and bit of an obscure situation but I'll leave an answer in case anyone runs into something similar.

My loader is contained in an Asset class - when another object requires the internal bitmap, it queries this class - if the bitmap's present, it returns it, if not it loads it with a loader and registers a callback for a COMPLETE event which is fired when the Loader has loaded and transferred its contents to a BitmapData instance.

The stupid mistake I'd made was that, if several objects were querying the same (as-yet-unloaded) asset, it would start reloading the asset each time, creating a new Loader as it did so...so when the first Loader was complete, it would fire an event but no reference to it would exist, not only creating a memory leak but causing the Asset class to extract the BitmapData from the most-recently-created Loader, which was not complete! The asynchronous nature of Loader is the reason it worked sometimes, as on occasion the final Loader would be ready in time for BitmapData extraction.

Simple solution was to create an internal boolean, _isLoading, which is set to true the first time load() is called - any subsequent calls are ignored if it's true, but callbacks still registered, works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to adjust the image decoding policy for the loader - to ensure it decodes the image before COMPLETE fires - then the width and height etc should be reliable.

To do it, just add a suitable LoaderContext object to the Loader.load method:

```
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
//set decode policy
loaderContext.imageDecodingPolicy = ImageDecodingPolicy.ON_LOAD;
//load image
loader.load(yourUrl, loaderContext);
```

The default decode policy is ImageDecodingPolicy.ON_DEMAND - which doesnt decode the image until it is actually required.

Lang docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ImageDecodingPolicy.html

Comment: Hey, I'd never heard of this so looked like the answer but sadly no joy, same thing happens!